# Вставка HTML через JS

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток! Возник следующий вопрос: в зависимости от результата проверки некоторого условия в JS нужно выводить на HTML определенный блок из двух. Видимость не подходит, есть элементы, которые не могут выводиться 2 раза. Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Либо подключаем Jquery, что намного удобнее, если нет маниакального стремления строить велосипеды(на что мое мнение, надо построить свою ось для начала, чтобы уже никто не подкопался), либо возможно стандартным js [Доступ к элементам DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodes_access.asp).
Вариант с Jquery до безумия прост
1.Подключаем библиотеку
2.Присваиваем элементам id  к примеру

```
 div id="blockN"
```

3.Меняем их содержимое

```
$("#blockN").html(Вставьте свою разметку сюда);
```

4.Гуглим "Jquery селекторы"

Comment: Большое спасибо! жаль, что у меня нет столько времени, чтобы с этим разобраться...

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(someid).innerHTML = somehtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
condition?document.getElementById (id).innerHTML = value;
```

Надеюсь, разберешся :)

Comment: `true?into():undefined;` бесполезная конструкция.

Comment: @AGS17 вставил чисто для примера. Вместо true - условие, inro - сама функция. Сейчас изменю